# Php - Display image from Database using path (PDO)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I tried to display image from database,

- image in directory
- path in database

  ```
  require_once "Connection.php";
  class DisplayDataImageProfile {
  function showImageProfile(){
      $connection = new Connection();
      $conn = $connection->getConnection();

      $id = $_GET['id'];

      try{
          $sqlDisplay = "SELECT photo FROM frofile WHERE id =$id";
          $getImage = $conn->prepare($sqlDisplay);
          $getImage->execute();
          $getImage->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

          foreach($getImage as $data){
              header('Content-type: image/jpg');
              // echo "<img src='$data'>";
              echo $data;
          }

      }catch (PDOException $e){
          echo "Error : " + $e->getMessage();
      }
  }}
  ```

after that i call in html page like this :

```
<img src="DisplayDataImageProfile .php?id=3" align="center" />
```

i got problem that image cannot retrieve from database using path.
other case on webpage the image something like broken image displayed.

for currently i just display one image.

Comment: are you wants to display single image or image in listing?

Comment: use `$data['photo']` instead of just `$data`

Comment: @devpro Post that as the answer ;)

Comment: @red Your code is open to SQL injection, you're not preparing correctly.

Comment: @Matt: thanks for suggestion brother, posted... :)

Comment: if you already saved image in the database, you don't need path. Path is needed if you save `reference` to the image in the database. in your case with content type and all, looks like you are saving image as `blob` in the database, correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @DeepKakkar : for currently i just need display one image.

Comment: @MuhammedM. : no sir, i already save as string in database.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the proper method.

Instead of fetchAll() which returns a nested array, you have to use fetchColumn() which returns single value. And you should be using prepared statements properly:

```
$sql = "SELECT photo FROM frofile WHERE id = ?";
$getImage = $conn->prepare($sqlDisplay);
$getImage->execute([$_GET['id']]);
header('Content-type: image/jpg');
echo $getImage->fetchColumn();
```

**Edit:** If you don't have an image itself in database but only path to the image, then you don't need this code at all. Get rid of Display.php and just select your path in the script that is echoing

```
<img src="Display.php?id=3" align="center" />
```

and echo selected path instead of `Display.php?id=3`.

Comment: now it gave me broken image. on web page like display an image, but broken image.

Comment: I added header to my code. And obviously you have to have an image in your database stored properly.

Comment: in my database i just store image path, and the image in the folder

still gave me broken image.

Comment: so **you don't need no Display.php script at all!**

Comment: sorry sir, once again my question, after i followed your code, i got error that `id` is Undefined.
when should i define the variable `id` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$data` as:

```
$data['photo']
```

instead of just

```
$data
```

Because `$getImage` consist on associative array, so you can not use like your example, you need to use index for print data.

Comment: now it gave me broken image. on web page like display an image, but broken image.

Comment: @red: check url in view source

Comment: something like this : `localhost:49185/insertData/AdminPage.php`

where image will be displayed

Comment: @red: and what is the result of `print_r($getImage);`

Comment: still broken image sir.

Comment: @red: what r u getting in print_r($getImage);